# Using Linked List as an object in a class in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to implement a "facebook" like problem.

I have created a class called `User`.  A user has a list of friends.

I tried this using a C++ vector and it worked without any problems.

Then I tried changing the vector to a `LinkedList`, using a template class I have.

The template has a copy constructor and destructor.

I have tested and debugged the template for other datatypes.

```
class User
{
private:
    string uname;
    //vector<User> myfriends;
    LinkedList<User> myfriends;

public:
    User() { uname = "none"; }
    User(string n) { uname = n; }
    string getName() { return uname; }
    void addFriend(User &u) 
    { 
        //add u to me
        myfriends.appendNode(u);

        //add "me" to u
        u.myfriends.appendNode(*this); //causes problem?

        //myfriends.push_back(u);  //when using vector
        //u.myfriends.push_back(*this); //works when using vector

    }
    void listFriends()
    {
        cout << uname << " has " << myfriends.getSize() << " friends" << endl;
        myfriends.displayList();  //prints values in linked list
    }

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, User u)
    {
        out << u.uname;
        return out;
    }

};
```

I want the addFriend function to make a "mutual" connection.

This works when I use a `vector`, but when using this `LinkedList` and this testing program:

```
User u1("joe");
User u2("sam");

u1.addFriend(u2);
u1.listFriends();
```

I get the correct output

```
joe has 1 friends
sam
```

However I also get a runtime error which tells me something funky is happening with my pointers.

> "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly."

I am using Visual Studio Express 2017.

I am trying to figure out if there is some basic flaw with making the connections this way, trying to draw some pictures to work it out.

Any thoughts on what might be causing the runtime error?

Here's the `displayList()` function:

```
template <class T> 
void LinkedList<T>::displayList() 
{ 
    //"walk" the list and print each value 
    ListNode *nodePtr; 
    //to walk the list
    //start at the beginning 
    nodePtr = head; 
    //while there is a node to print 
    while (nodePtr) { 
        //display the value 
        cout << nodePtr->data << endl; 
        //move to next node 
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next; 
    } 
}
```

Here is displayList code in LinkedList template

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::displayList()
{
    //"walk" the list and print each value
    ListNode *nodePtr;  //to walk the list
                        //start at the beginning
    nodePtr = head;
    //while there is a node to print
    while (nodePtr)
    {
        //display the value
        cout << nodePtr->data << endl;
        //move to next node
        nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
    }
}
```

Here is appendNode

```
template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::appendNode(T value)
{
    ListNode *newNode;  //to point to a new node
    ListNode *nodePtr;  //to move through the list

                        //allicate a new node and store value
    newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    //if list is empty make this the first node
    if (!head)
        head = newNode;
    else // insert at end of list
    {
        //initialize nodePtr to head of list
        nodePtr = head;
        //"walk" the listt to find the last node
        while (nodePtr->next)  //if not null this is true
        {
            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
        }
        //nodePtr now points to last node in list
        //add the new node
        nodePtr->next = newNode;
        //remember it's next has already been assigned to null
    }
    numElements++;

}
```

Here is link
https://repl.it/@prprice16/GrowlingFastRule

Comment: If you want us to help with bugs in your LinkedList you need to post a minimal example.

Comment: Also you'll get much better help if you post a https://repl.it link

Comment: The linked list works in other programs, but I could post it.  My question is about the reciprocal nature of the lists in two objects pointing to each other, whether there is a fundamental issue there that I need to consider.

Comment: show your `displayList`

Comment: https://repl.it/@prprice16/GrowlingFastRule

Comment: Runs but gives*** Error in `./main': double free or corruption (fasttop):

Comment: *** Error in `./main': free(): invalid pointer:

Comment: template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::displayList()
{
 //"walk" the list and print each value
 ListNode *nodePtr;  //to walk the list
      //start at the beginning
 nodePtr = head;
 //while there is a node to print
 while (nodePtr)
 {
  //display the value
  cout << nodePtr->data << endl;
  //move to next node
  nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
 }
}

Comment: sorry displayList code did not format correctly, but it is in repl.it link posted above

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It's best to edit your question to include the new information, not add a string of comments.  I suggest you edit it then delete the comments.  It might also help to read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve]

Comment: Also, with a debug build you might be able to look at the call stack to see what went horribly wrong.  If not, adding some logging / trace code should help.

Comment: Still missing the `appendNode` code.

Comment: Best way to debug random crashes is AppVerif.exe under C:\windows\system32. Open it, add your application, press save, close AppVerif. Then run your prog under visual studio debugger. Remember to remove your app from AppVerif settings when you are done (it makes your program use lots of extra cpu and memory). If it's working, you should see lines in VS debugger output like "application verifier enabled". Obviously this requires a debug build

Comment: Please read about **the rule of three**, but also re-do your design using `LinkedList<User*>`. It is not possible to do a friends network with `LinkedList<User>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
LinkedList<User> myfriends;
```

When you do

```
void addFriend(User &u) 
{ 
    //...
}
```

You will do a full copy of User, including the LinkedList object in it.
However, inside your LinkedList, you did not specify an assignment operator, meaning your head for the User passed in will be directly assigned, leaving you with 2 LinkedList with the same head.

Hence the same head pointer will be freed twice.

Comment: Aaahhh!!!  So I need to overload operator= to do a deep copy of the list?  I think I get it...!

Comment: It is better for you to simply use a LinkedList<User*> instead.

Comment: wait or do I need to overload operator== in User?  to make sure it actually makes a copy?  But I want to modify the user object that is passed in (to make the friendship mutual).

Comment: When you say simply use a LinkedList<User> ... but I need the list inside User, that is what I have.

Comment: Or do I need a copy constructor for User?

Comment: If you want to make the LinkedList more versatile in situations like this, you should implement the assignment operator. Also, take note of the additional * in the LinkedList<User*> comment. It is always better to store a pointer instead of copying everything inside the other user. This is a much better solution in both logic and efficiency.

Comment: Oh ... didn't see the * ... thanks for giving me food for thought, I knew something was going on, was trying to visualize and think through the problem.  I will work on it.  Thanks again!

Comment: @PamelaPrice To make it clear, his suggestion of a copy assign `operator=` for `LinkedList` will (presumably) resolve the crashing. His additional suggestion of `User*` vs `User` in the linked list is unrelated to this crash (not that I disagree with it).

Comment: And overloading operator= in LinkedList will basically use the same code I have in copy constructor correct?

Comment: wow yes overloading operator= in LinkedList did the trick!!  MANY THANKS!!!

Comment: Almost, except you have to take care to clean up your current container before copying the other list. The question has been answered and the baton is in your hands now, go ahead and experiment yourself. Do your best to understand what is happening and what is the correct way to do things yourself via researching. You will also learn more along the way.

Comment: @Jay Wai Tan Just a quick clarification, what do you mean by "clean up your current container"?

Comment: If your current LinkedList has items in it, when you do an assignment, you have to cleanup before you copy.

Comment: The user class should be uncopyable in the first place, it"s the only sane way to program this kind of application.